# Latexdiff figure

Tags: latexdiff

it is the first time that I use latexdiff. 
I am comparing two files, old.tex and new.tex. In the old.tex, I have "figure_old.eps". In the new.tex, I have used a different figure "figure_new.eps". In the output of latexdiff, that I call diff.tex, I don't see that this changing in the figure has been highlighted in any way.
Does someone have a tip ?

Comment: In the diff.tex file itself it IS marked up and looks like this (no linebreaks in comments makes this a bit hard to read): \DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \includegraphics{fig-old} %DIFDELCMD < %%% \DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \includegraphics{fig-new} \DIFaddend If you search for DIFaddbegin tags you can look through the source for such invisible changes. But I take it you want it to show up somehow in the marked-up version - you can define \DIFaddbegin to output a marginal comment but this will affect all changes. Otherwise it is a feature request best placed at latexdiff github page.